# Passing an uninitialized struct to a function, why is it not null?

Tags: c, struct

I've been scratching my head quite a while at this one.  I'm creating my node without any values (and even tried initializing it and a pointer and set it = NULL), but when I get inside the insert function head_ does not evaluate to NULL.  I can check for head_->id = NULL but I don't think I should have to do that.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I'm trying to build and traverse a linked list and am certainly not off to a good start!  The output is:

head_ = 
not null!?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
        int id;
        struct node *next;
    };
int main(void){
    struct node head;
    int entered_id;
    insert(&head, 1);
}
void insert(struct node* head_, int new_id){  
    printf("\nhead_ = %s", head_);
    if(!head_){
        printf("\nnull");
    }
    else
        printf("\nnot null!?");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: use struct node * head; and pass head. struct node head  allocates space for head as it is declaration of variable

Comment: `&head` won't be `NULL` because it is the address of an object. And `head.id` won't be `NULL` because you did not initialize the struct.

Comment: @TejasPatel - You shoukd put your comment as the answer.

Comment: Once you've got over this, you'll probably need to fix the interface to your function.  If you're going to allocate nodes, you either need a function to initialize a list, or you'll need to let the insert function return a pointer to the new head of the list, or take a pointer to a pointer to modify the pointer in the calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
        int id;
        struct node *next;
    };
int main(void){
    struct node * head = NULL; // create a pointer instead of declaring structure variable
    int entered_id;
    insert(head, 1);
}
void insert(struct node* head_, int new_id){  
   // printf("\nhead_ = %s", head_); can you print structure as string?
    if(!head_){
        printf("\nnull");
    }
    else
        printf("\nnot null!?");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

If you use struct node head, it will create an object which occupies space and so is not NULL. What you want is a pointer to an object which initially points to nothing and so is null.

Comment: Why are you using an uninitialized variable? You don't initialize `head`.

Comment: This did do the trick.  Based on an above comment it looks like I was incorrectly expecting the address to evaluate to NULL.  Now I still need to pass by reference so that I can modify the struct itself, so I'll tinker with this some more.

Answer (score 0):

The struct is not a pointer to null because it was allocated. If it were declared as:

```
struct node *head;
```

then, it would possibly point to NULL, but its not defined.

```
struct node *head = NULL;
```

would guarantee its pointing to NULL. Even in that case, you can't allocate it in another function that way. If you in insert did

```
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

then, when main came back, head would still be NULL, and you would have a memory leak.

The way it is defined,

```
struct node head; //allocates sizeof(struct node) bytes on the stack of main, which is destroyed after main exits.
```

Make sense?